# NSUserDefaults: detecting nil

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have some code in my classes to read from NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
score = [defs integerForKey:@"score"];
```

this causes a crash.

Im guessing it is because the score value is nil or doesnt exist.

How can I check if it is nil?

EDIT.

The following code causes a crash when storing to NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defs setInteger:0 forKey:@"score"];
    [defs setInteger:3 forKey:@"lives"];
    [defs release];
```

Im not sure what the issue is

On some crashes there isnt even a crash report in the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the documentation, *"if the specified key does not exist, this method returns 0"*. So integerForKey will always return an NSInteger, even if you haven't set it.

Edit:
Now you've edited your question, I can see the problem. You are releasing NSUserDefaults. There is no reason to do this. Remove the [release] line from your code.

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] returns a singleton class. You don't own it, so you shouldn't release it. Review the Apple [Memory Mangement Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) if you're confused about when to retain/release.

Comment: I get the following error -[__NSCFSet integerForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69697b0'

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Weird thing is I was releasing it in the past and it worked. anyway. Thanks.